# Dynamic cell height follow its content inside

Tags: uitableview, swift, uilabel

I have a static cell which contains only a `UILabel` on my TableViewController. I am able to update my label on viewDidLoad method using the code below,

```
myLabel.text = "A\nB\nC\nD..."
```

but the cell remain its height even on breaking lines, all the text can be seen, it just display over the cell. How can I let my TableViewCell's height follow my label to get larger, like force to layout again?

I tried update the value after the label changed but nothing's happen.

```
myCell.frame.size.height = 200  //if calculate myself
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change your UITableViewCell's height, you must return the height in UITableView's delegate method `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you can caculate the text height releted cell.

Comment: Is that no way to set the height after tableview is loaded? Because I may change my text afterward.

Comment: Yes, you can. When you change the Cell data, you can reload that call using `tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:` or reload all tableView `tableView reloadData`, then method `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` could be called and you return newest height for cell,